why text color not showing up
Any idea why the color for the geom_text is not working? I was expecting A,B,C at the bottom to be red, yellow and blue, but they all showing black now.
library(tidyverse)

ln <- data.frame(xval=c(1,2,3),yval=c(3,2,5))
txt <- data.frame(xval=c(1,2,3),yval=c(0.5,0.5,0.5),txt=c("A","B","C"),anc=c("red","yellow","blue"))

ggplot() + 
geom_line(data=ln, aes(x=xval, y=yval, color="line"), linewidth=1) +
geom_point(data=ln, aes(x=xval, y=yval, color="dot"), size=2.5) +
geom_text(data=txt,  aes(x=xval, y=yval, label=txt, color=anc), size=3) +
ylim(0, 6) + xlim(0, 4) +
scale_colour_manual(name="", values = c("line"="cyan", "dot"="black"))


Tried above code, I was expecting red, yellow and blue for A,B and C, but surprised to all showing black

Your color scale only has two values mapped, "line" and "dot". Any other values will be assigned the color for missing values, which is grey. If you want five colors, you need to supply a vector of length 5 to values.

I actually tried  scale_colour_manual(name="", values = c("line"="cyan","dot"="black","A"="red","B"="yellow","C"="blue")), and removed color=anc from aes(), but still not working.

It sounds like you want some layers to use scale_colour_manual and others to use scale_colour_identity, which is possible using the ggnewscale package:
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=ln, aes(x=xval, y=yval, color="line"), linewidth=1) +
  geom_point(data=ln, aes(x=xval, y=yval, color="dot"), size=2.5) +
  ylim(0, 6) + xlim(0, 4) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="", values = c("line"="cyan", "dot"="black")) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_colour() +
  geom_text(data=txt,  aes(x=xval, y=yval, label=txt, color=anc), size=3) +
  scale_color_identity()


Or, alternatively, you could specify those colors manually, but that kind of defeats the point of specifying them by name initially, and then they'd appear in the legend...
scale_colour_manual(name="", values = c("line"="cyan", "dot"="black", 
                    "red" = "red", "yellow" = "yellow", "blue" = "blue")) +
...


Or you could specify color outside of aes(), so it is not mapped to a data.frame variable but rather to the values specified in that layer:
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=ln, aes(x=xval, y=yval, color="line"), linewidth=1) +
  geom_point(data=ln, aes(x=xval, y=yval, color="dot"), size=2.5) +
  ylim(0, 6) + xlim(0, 4) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="", values = c("line"="cyan", "dot"="black")) +
  geom_text(data=txt, aes(x=xval, y=yval, label=txt), 
            color = c("red","yellow","blue"),
            size=3) 



Thanks. Is it possible without using extra package like ggnewscale?

Not that I'm aware, but maybe someone knows a way. I guess you could specify different layers for each color and specify the colors outside of aes(), but that's kinda clunky if you have many.

As you said, this will add to legend too, which is not what I want.

If the color is specified outside aes I don’t see how it would be added to the legend.

Edited to show how we could specify the colors with hard-coding in the layer itself and outside of aes(), so they don't get added to the legend.

As of ggplot2 >= 3.5.0 there is no need to use scale_color_identity (and hence no need for ggnewscale). Instead we can wrap in AsIs´ aka I()insideaes(), i.e. aes(..., color = I(anc))`. see https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2024/02/ggplot2-3-5-0/#ignoring-scales

Ooh, thanks, I had missed that. https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2024/02/ggplot2-3-5-0/#ignoring-scales

I(anc) inside aes works great, thanks Jon!
